# What are the differences between segment trees, interval trees, binary indexed trees and range trees?

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm, interval-tree, segment-tree

What are differences between segment trees, interval trees, binary indexed trees and range trees in terms of:

- Key idea/definition
- Applications
- Performance/order in higher dimensions/space consumption

Please do not just give definitions.

Comment: It is not a duplicate, That question is if fenwick trees is generalization of interval tress, and my question is more specific and different.

Comment: It has not been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795989/are-interval-segment-fenwick-trees-the-same, the answer there just gives definition.

Comment: How is it too broad? "What are some differences between x and y?" is as clear and focused as it gets. This is a very good question.

Comment: And there is no good answer for this available anywhere. A good answer will be great for the community

Comment: Most of these data structures (except Fenwick trees) are reviewed in this pdf: ["Interval, Segment, Range, and Priority Search Trees"](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~dtlee/dtlee/CRCbook_chapter18.pdf) (by D. T. Lee). Or you can read it as a chapter from this book: ["Handbook of Data Structures and Applications"](http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Structures-Applications-Computer-Information/dp/1584884355).

Comment: Not a greatest answer but still worth reading http://www.quora.com/Data-Structures/What-are-the-major-differences-between-segment-trees-interval-trees-binary-indexed-trees-and-range-trees

Comment: I read that already before asking the question, its not really good

Comment: If I didn't know about TopCoder et al., this list would look pretty random. Only segment trees and interval trees have the same applications, and there are several divide-and-conquer data structures missing.

Comment: The "Interval, Segment, Range, and Priority Search Trees" (by D. T. Lee) was very helpful.

Answer (score 396, accepted):

All these data structures are used for solving different problems:

- **Segment tree** stores intervals, and optimized for "*which of these intervals contains a given point*" queries.
- **Interval tree** stores intervals as well, but optimized for "*which of these intervals overlap with a given interval*" queries. It can also be used for point queries - similar to segment tree.
- **Range tree** stores points, and optimized for "*which points fall within a given interval*" queries.
- **Binary indexed tree** stores items-count per index, and optimized for "*how many items are there between index m and n*" queries.

Performance / Space consumption for one dimension:

- **Segment tree** - O(n logn) preprocessing time, O(k+logn) query time, O(n logn) space
- **Interval tree** - O(n logn) preprocessing time, O(k+logn) query time, O(n) space
- **Range tree** - O(n logn) preprocessing time, O(k+logn) query time, O(n) space
- **Binary Indexed tree** - O(n logn) preprocessing time, O(logn) query time, O(n) space

(k is the number of reported results).

All data structures can be dynamic, in the sense that the usage scenario includes both data  changes and queries:

- **Segment tree** - interval can be added/deleted in O(logn) time (see [here](http://3glab.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~spoon/courses/CS631100/Lecture05_handout.pdf))
- **Interval tree** - interval can be added/deleted in O(logn) time
- **Range tree** - new points can be added/deleted in O(logn) time (see [here](http://www.cs.unb.ca/tech-reports/documents/TR95_100.pdf))
- **Binary Indexed tree** - the items-count per index can be increased in O(logn) time

Higher dimensions (d>1):

- **Segment tree** - O(n(logn)^d) preprocessing time, O(k+(logn)^d) query time, O(n(logn)^(d-1)) space
- **Interval tree** - O(n logn) preprocessing time, O(k+(logn)^d) query time, O(n logn) space
- **Range tree** - O(n(logn)^d) preprocessing time, O(k+(logn)^d) query time, O(n(logn)^(d-1))) space
- **Binary Indexed tree** - O(n(logn)^d) preprocessing time, O((logn)^d) query time, O(n(logn)^d) space

Comment: I really get the impression that segment trees < interval trees from this. Is there any reason to prefer a segment tree? E.g. implementation simplicity?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Segment trees based algorithms have advantages in certain more complex high-dimensional variants of the intervals query. For example, finding which non-axis-parallel line-segments intersect with a 2D window.

Comment: Thanks, I'd be interested in any elaboration you could give on that.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, segment trees have another interesting use: RMQs (range minimum queries) in O(log N) time where N is the overall interval size.

Comment: @LiorKogan Segment trees should only take up O(n) in one dimension if implemented properly. Use an array of size 2*n.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone: This is true when you're using a segment tree for finding sums of a given range. For interval queries, as discussed above, you'll first need to sort the intervals by their endpoints.

Comment: Maybe a 1D Binary Indexed Tree can be built in O(n)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068521/is-it-possible-to-build-a-fenwick-tree-in-on?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I think `B+ tree` can absolutely do what `Range` and `binary indexed` tree can do. Am I right? It can also do what interval/segment tree can do but may be not as efficient.

Comment: What is the difference of 2d R-tree and 2d segment tree ?

Comment: I also heard that `interval-trees` are **balanced and more compressed** than `segment trees`. Is that segment tree better as off-line tree and interval-tree be more on-line (where more insertion is going on).

Comment: Why are segment trees O(n log n) space? They store N leaves + N /2 + N/4 + ... + N/2^(log N), and this sum is O(N) if I am not mistaken. Also @icc97 answer also reports O(N) space.

Comment: @LiorKogan Thank you - I had read the comment, but I am not sure how the need to keep things sorted would translate into an increase in space complexity - I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on it! :-)

Comment: @Ant: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree#Storage_requirements

Comment: @j_random_hacker: See for example http://cs.yazd.ac.ir/farshi/Teaching/CG3921/Slides/chapter10%20-section3.pdf

Comment: I used to think that [RMQ (Range Minimum/Maximum Query)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-range-minimum-query/) and [Range Sum Query](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/) are main application for Segment Tree ._.

Answer (score 36):

Not that I can add anything to [Lior's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17504505/327074), but it seems like it could do with a good table.

#### One Dimension

`k` is the number of reported results

| Operation | Segment | Interval | Range | Indexed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Preprocessing | n logn | n logn | n logn | n logn |
| Query | k+logn | k+logn | k+logn | logn |
| Space | n logn | n | n | n |
| Insert/Delete | logn | logn | logn | logn |

#### Higher Dimensions

`d > 1`

| Operation | Segment | Interval | Range | Indexed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Preprocessing | n(logn)^d | n logn | n(logn)^d | n(logn)^d |
| Query | k+(logn)^d | k+(logn)^d | k+(logn)^d | (logn)^d |
| Space | n(logn)^(d-1) | n logn | n(logn)^(d-1)) | n(logn)^d |

Comment: What do you mean by reported results ?

Comment: @ps06756 search algorithms often have a runtime of log(n) where n is the inputsize but can yield results that are linear in n which can't be done in logarithmic time (outputting n numbers in log(n) time is not possible).

Comment: Shouldn't Segment Tree have `O(n logn) space` in the first table?

Comment: @Danny_ds - thanks I fixed that when you commented

Answer (score 1):

The bounds for preprocessing and space for segment trees and binary indexed trees can be improved:

- Segment trees can be stored in `2n` space and subsequently built in `2n = O(n)` using dynamic programming, if you forgo adding intervals at any arbitrary point: https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html#toc-tgt-6
- BIT can be built in `n`, see this answer: [Is it possible to build a Fenwick tree in O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068521/is-it-possible-to-build-a-fenwick-tree-in-on?rq=1)
- BIT also supports append to end as an operation in `O(log(n))` time