# Double for loop performance issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, object, for-loop

Apologies about the vague titles, wasn't really sure how else to describe the problem.

I recently ran into a case where I have to loop through an array of objects to compare multiple value, I opted for using a for loop in a for loop to compare each object with every other object.

While this works fine on small arrays, once my array gets a little bigger (say 10,000 objects) performance tends to be a big issue.

This array contains these kind of objects:

```
[{ char: '_', from: 0, to: 2, chrLength: 2 },
{ char: '_', from: 0, to: 7, chrLength: 7 },
{ char: 'a', from: 1, to: 3, chrLength: 2 },
{ char: 'a', from: 1, to: 6, chrLength: 5 },
{ char: '_', from: 2, to: 7, chrLength: 5 },
{ char: 'a', from: 3, to: 6, chrLength: 3 }]
```

The idea is that I can only select objects where the `from` and `to` don't overlap with any other object. (`from` and `to` are indexes in another array)

So for the example array, possible outcomes would be:

```
[{ char: '_', from: 0, to: 2, chrLength: 2 },
 { char: 'a', from: 1, to: 3, chrLength: 2 },
 { char: 'a', from: 1, to: 6, chrLength: 5 },
 { char: 'a', from: 3, to: 6, chrLength: 3 }]
```

The way I handled it was as follows:

```
var canUse = true,
    posibilities = [];
for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    canUse = true;
    for(var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        if((results[i].from < results[j].from && results[i].to > results[j].to)) {
            canUse = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(canUse) posibilities.push(results[i]);
}
```

Seeing performance is quite terrible with larger arrays, I'm wondering if there is a better solution to do this?

Comment: shouldn't `{ char: '_', from: 2, to: 7, chrLength: 5 }` be in the outcomes?

Comment: @LIUFA: No, because `{ char: 'a', from: 3, to: 6, chrLength: 3 }` fits inside it.

Comment: @Jashwant Not quite sure what you mean, can you provide a small example?

Comment: @woutr_be, sorry misinterpreted your question. Deleted my comment.

Comment: Proper data structure would help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466218/what-are-the-differences-between-segment-trees-interval-trees-binary-indexed-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/5jsSb/10/)):

1. You need some sort of self-balancing tree supporting insert and remove operations of O(log n). For the sake of simplicity I've used Red-Black Tree.
2. You need to use mid point of your interval as a key i.e. `(from + to)/2`.
3. Suppose you have already "inserted" `k` items into your tree and are about to insert `k+1`. Your steps are:
4. If `k+1` covers the root - ignore it.
5. If `k+1` is covered by the root - remove the root from the tree and make another attempt.
6. Else continue to the left or the right subtree by comparing `k+1`'s mid to the root's one.
7. When everything is inserted traverse the resulting tree collecting every node.
8. Profit... I've used 4 times the array of yours by concating it with itself. The result on my machine under Chrome is 116ms (cold start) and 64ms (after warm up).

Code

```
 function process() {
    console.log('Processing results of length: ' + l);

    console.time('Processing');

    var comparator = function(a, b) { //Comparator to build a tree
           return a.mid - b.mid;
        },
        isAinB = function(a, b) { //util function to check if a is inside b
            return b.from < a.from && b.to > a.to;    
        },
        rbtree = new RBTree(comparator), //Build an empty tree
        i = results.length - 1, item, posibilities = [];

    function check(root, x) { //Recursive checker
        var data;        

        if(!root) { //Either tree is empty or we've reached a leaf
            rbtree.insert(x);
            return;
        }

        data = root.data;

        if(isAinB(data, x)) { //4
            return;    
        }
        if(isAinB(x, data)) { //5
            rbtree.remove(data);
            check(rbtree._root, x);
            return;
        }    

        check(root[comparator(data, x) > 0 ? 'left' : 'right'], x); //6
    }

    for(; i >= 0; i--) { 
        item = results[i];
        item.mid = (item.from + item.to)/2; //2
        check(rbtree._root, item); //3
    }

    rbtree.each(function(item) { //7
        posibilities.push(item);
    });
    console.timeEnd('Processing');

    console.log(posibilities.length);
}
```

BTW I've used this [RBTree implementation](https://github.com/vadimg/js_bintrees). Not sure if it is the best one :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the example, I don't have any experience with trees, looking into RBTree now to see if I can re-create your demo.

Comment: @woutr_be Self-balancing trees are very useful data structures when you have some sort of comparison based queries. https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms chapters 12-13

Answer (score 1):

Start by sorting the objects on the `chrLength` property. When you look for objects that keep an object from being included, you only have to check the objects that are at least two characters shorter.

```
results.sort(function(x, y){ return x.chrLength - y.chrLength; });

var posibilities = [];
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  var canUse = true, len = results[i].chrLength - 2;
  for (var j = 0; results[j].chrLength <= len; j++) {
    if((results[i].from < results[j].from && results[i].to > results[j].to)) {
      canUse = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(canUse) posibilities.push(results[i]);
}
```

With your example data, this reduces the number of checks from 36 in the in the original code to only 8.

Comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/5jsSb/

#### Edit:

You can make an array where each item is an array of objects with the same `chrLength`, and then sort each array on the `from` property. That way you can easily skip to the point where the objects start to overlap, and stop comparing as soon as they don't overlap any more:

```
var map = [];
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  var ch = results[i].chrLength;
  while (map.length <= ch) map.push([]);
  map[ch].push(results[i]);
}
for (var i = 1; i < map.length; i++) {
  map[i].sort(function(x, y){ return x.from - y.from; });
}

var posibilities = [];
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  var canUse = true, len = results[i].chrLength - 2, from = results[i].from, to = results[i].to;
  for (var j = 1; canUse && j <= len; j++) {
    if (map[j][map[j].length - 1].from > from) {
      var k;
      for (k = 0; map[j][k].from <= from; k++);
      for (;k < map[j].length && map[j][k].from < to; k++) {
        if (map[j][k].to < to) {
          canUse = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(canUse) posibilities.push(results[i]);
}
```

This splits the checks for the `from` and the `to` properties in two stages, so the number of complete checks (where `map[j][k].to < to` is evaluated) is actually smaller than the total number of objects.

Disclaimer: Naturally you would need to verify that the code does the right thing. I have checked that the result has the same number of items, but I haven't compared each item.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to reduce the amount of checks, but with some larger arrays it still takes quite a bit. Just wondering if there's any way to eliminate items before performing a for loop

Comment: @woutr_be: How does the number of checks change for larger sets? Consider that you can't ever get any better than O(n), i.e. at least one check per item. Can you show a larger example set? It's hard to find any useful patterns in a small set, that could be used for ellimination.

Comment: Sure, for example, here's one with 1000 items http://jsfiddle.net/5jsSb/1/

And here's one more extreme: http://jsfiddle.net/5jsSb/3/ (although my final array is double the size)

Comment: @woutr_be: Nice, that made it easier to test some ideas. I made some improvements, and posted the code above. There are some more optimisations that might be done, but it's hard to analyse what's actually happening in the code in a fiddle, it hardly runs at all with that much data. The browser actually crashed once. :)

Comment: Guys, I think you are on a wrong way. You need some sort of data structure that will answer the question 'if a given interval has overlaps' in O(log n) times. There is such a data structure called interval tree (google for it). It takes O(n*log n) to construct it and n times O(log n) to check every interval for overlaps. The resulting complexity will be O(n*log n).

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: That's possible, but this is an unusual kind of overlap where standard solutions doesn't fit straight off. For example the interval 5 to 10 doesn't have overlaps in the intervals 4 to 6, 5 to 8, 7 to 10 or 8 to 12, but in the intervals 6 to 8 and 7 to 9.

Comment: @Guffa This fact actually makes the problem easier. It allows to eliminate 'overlaping' intervals when building the tree.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: I don't think so, you need all of the intervals, as any interval can affect another interval.

Comment: @Guffa How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/5jsSb/10/ If an interval is to the left of the current root it can't affect anything to the right, thats the point. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, once `canUse` is `false` you don't need to carry on with the inner loop.

You can either add a `break;` or change the second for loop to be:

`for (var j = 0; canUse && (j < l); j++)`

and you'll probably see a useful speed up.

Comment: Nice spot, totally overlooked that.