# Finding a set of targets that overlap a point in time

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vectorization

At a point in time, I need to find all Targets that have points earlier and later than that time.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
for current_time = sorted_set_of_times;
    target_set = find([Targets.First_Time] <= current_time ... 
        & [Targets.Last_Time] >= current_time);
    % Using target_set here. Targets are not modified within this loop
end
```

MATLAB profiler is telling me that this line takes about 40 minutes with 40,000 calls.

**Is there a way that I can do this more efficiently?**

`current_time` is incremented in a for_loop in order. I was thinking that the fact that this is always increasing could be used to shortcut some of the testing. For example `Targets.First_Time <= current_time` will be a subset of `Targets.First_Time <= current_time+n`.

`numel(sorted_set_of_times)` is approximately 40,000

`numel(Targets)` is more than 10 million

Comment: 1. struct could be causing it to be slower. 2. logical indexing might help remove find and thus get some performance improvement. Is `current_time` incremented with constant stepsize? Could you share more of the related code, the loop code maybe?

Comment: Hi Divakar, sorry I can't share the actual code because it is on an air-gapped system. `current_time` does not increment evenly, but it is sorted.

Comment: Do `Targets.First_Time` or `Targets.Last_Time` change within that loop?

Comment: No, Targets is unmodified

Comment: `numel(sorted_set_of_times)`?

Comment: Approximately 40,000. Targets is 10M+. This is why I am thinking a sorted set of first/last times would be a lot more efficient than doing an O(n) search on 10 million targets 40,000 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Vectorized solution with `bsxfun` -

```
eqcond = bsxfun(@le,Targets.First_Time,sorted_set_of_times) & bsxfun(@ge,Targets.Last_Time,sorted_set_of_times);
[r,c] = find(eqcond);
for k =1:numel(sorted_set_of_times)
    target_set = r(c==k);
end
```

**Suggestion to use logical indexing (if applicable):** If you are using `target_set` to index into one of the dimensions of some variable named `target`, which is of length same as `Targets.First_Time` for that dimension, then instead of calculating `target_set` you can directly index into that dimension of `target` using `eqcond(:,ind)`, where `ind` would be the index to `sorted_set_of_times` in that loop. Thus, as an example, if you were indexing into the rows of `target` using `target_set` in your original code like `target(target_set,..)`, then you can do `target(eqcond(:,ind),..)` instead.

**Approach #2**

Reduced data approach -

```
vind = find(Targets.First_Time <= Targets.Last_Time); %//Indices to reduce Targets datasize
Targets.First_Time = Targets.First_Time(vind);
Targets.Last_Time = Targets.Last_Time(vind);
for current_time = sorted_set_of_times;
    target_set = vind([Targets.First_Time] <= current_time & [Targets.Last_Time] >= current_time);
end
```

**Approach #3 (Hybrid of Approaches #1,2)**

```
vind = find(Targets.First_Time <= Targets.Last_Time);
Targets.First_Time = Targets.First_Time(vind);
Targets.Last_Time = Targets.Last_Time(vind);
eqcond = bsxfun(@le,Targets.First_Time,sorted_set_of_times) & bsxfun(@ge,Targets.Last_Time,sorted_set_of_times);
[r,c] = find(eqcond);
for k =1:numel(sorted_set_of_times)
    target_set = vind(r(c==k));
end
```

**Suggestion to use logical indexing (if applicable):** On a similar discussion as stated for approach #1, you could perform logical indexing for this one too. Thus, using the same notations as for that discussion, instead of doing `target(target_set,..)`, you can do  `target(vind(eqcond(:,ind)),..)`.

Comment: Do `Targets.First_Time` and `sorted_set_of_times` have to be the same length here?

Comment: Woops, sorry. There are 10 million+ Targets, each with a First_Time and Last_Time.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley Ops my bad! I am assuming `Targets.First_Time` to be a column vector and `sorted_set_of_times` to be a row vector and also they don't have to be of the same lengths! Please ignore my previous comment!

Comment: No problem. Let me get back to you with the timing, it could still take a couple of hours to run through. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley Sure I would be rooting for this one! Keep in mind the row and column vector thing.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley Check out the just added `Approach #2`!

Comment: Does the second approach reduce to the askers approach if `First_Time` is not greater than `Last_Time` for each target?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Well that approach basically narrows the window for both First_Time and Last_Time, because of the way those are compared against current_time and thus reduces datasize for both First_Time and Last_Time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specific MATLAB instructions, but you can try following, trading memory for CPU:

1. Iterate over all targets as TARGET.
2. Find `min_time >= TARGET.First_Time` and `max_time <= TARGET.Last_Time` - using binary search.
3. Add TARGET to target_set for each time between min_time and max_time.
4. Iterate times as before, but use precomputed target_sets.

Comment: How does this save time?

Comment: O(n*m) -> O(n (ln m+result))

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at the problem description, and I think the use of an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or [KD Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) might be a better choice of data structure to the type of query you are doing.( Search based on ranges).

As in, let's say you build an interval tree with (startTime, EndTime), then you can execute the query on the ranges. 
Here's a very good [thread on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466218/what-are-the-differences-between-segment-trees-interval-trees-binary-indexed-t) about such range querying data structures

I don't know matlab, but it does seem to have support for [KD-TREES](http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/kdtreesearcher-class.html). 
I couldn't find information about Interval trees in matlab, but here's a [good tutorial](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/JamesStewart/378notes/22intervals/) on the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a brute force approach will never get much faster with these numbers. (Not by taking out structs or using logical indexing).

If you want a fast algorithm, I think the following can work:

1. Sort `current_time` (already done)
2. Sort target by `First_Time`
3. Find for all targets the starting point `S`
4. Sort by `Last_Time`
5. Find for all targets the endpoint `E`

If you have two sorted lists you just need to loop through each once to find the relevant point, significantly reducing the complexity of the operation.

Now you can just call your function for each target and use `current_time(S:E)`