# highest parallel event time

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I've had this Interview question and I would like to know how to solve that:
I have tried to find an answer for that on Google and here but no success
"Given a long list of events with start point and end point, find the time where intersection was highest "

not allowed to use any complex data structure

thank you

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466218/what-are-the-differences-between-segment-trees-interval-trees-binary-indexed-t

Answer (score 1):

Sort the times into ascending order and then run along them, incrementing a counter at a start and decrementing it at an end. The time with highest intersection should be the time when the counter reached its highest value.